# Opt-out of Wallpaper Tinting Windows

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit

macOS has an `Allow wallpaper tinting in windows` option in `Preferences > General`, which is unfortunately enabled by default.

Is there a way to disable this on a per-app basis?

Basically my entire application should act as if this setting was disabled.
It really messes with the readability inside the apps windows.

Comment: No. The whole point is that materials behave consistently within the OS. You can probably hack it with private API, but you shouldn’t.

Comment: Yeah. I just wish Apples design department employed qualified people...

Comment: Have you tried inserting a background view to your view hierarchy that covers the default tinting background view? You can set whatever color suitable for you on your custom background view.